# later.js doesn't get next datetime of cron expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, cron, laterjs

I use library later.js to get value next datetime from cron expression. But result's 5 times next isn't incorrect with time default ("7/16/2015 10:44:47"). This Result is deviation "hour".
this is my code.

```
<script src="../later.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var cron = "0 0/10 7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18 ? 1/1 1-5 *";

var d = new Date("7/16/2015 10:44:47");
later.date.timezone(true);
var sched = later.parse.cron(cron, true);

var results = later.schedule(sched).next(5,d);
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    document.write('<p>' + results[i].toLocaleString() + '</p>');
}
</script>
```

result incorrect :

> 14:00:00 16/7/2015
>
> 14:10:00 16/7/2015
>
> 14:20:00 16/7/2015
>
> 14:30:00 16/7/2015
>
> 14:40:00 16/7/2015

result correct use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to test:

> 1. Thursday, July 16, 2015 10:50 AM
> 2. Thursday, July 16, 2015 11:00 AM
> 3. Thursday, July 16, 2015 11:10 AM
> 4. Thursday, July 16, 2015 11:20 AM
> 5. Thursday, July 16, 2015 11:30 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question. Therefore, I post solution to refer.

In file later.js, It has function 'itemSorter' (line 999). this function sort array from crop expression (after it split ' ' and ',').

```
function itemSorter(a, b) {
    return isHash(a) && !isHash(b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Change this function to:

```
  function itemSorter(a, b) {
        if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
            return a > b ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return a - b;
    }
```

if you don't have later.js, you can download from URL:  https://github.com/bunkat/later.